# Setting default drive to be \Storage Card

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, cab

Is it possible to set "default drive" to be \Storage Card in Windows Mobile so that wceload.exe can install CAB file onto SD card, not default FLASH memory?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  CE has no notion of a "drive" nor does WCELOAD have a "default".  WCELOAD either gets it's info from the INF used to build the CAB, or if it's not present it asks the user where it should go.

**EDIT**

If you are the one creating the CAB file, then simply edit your INF.  In the [`CEStrings` section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms938390.aspx) set the `InstallDir` parameter.

Comment: Is it possible to set the InstallDir in INF file? If so, what is the parameter and how to set it?

Comment: Thanks, but I do create CAB file via Visual Studio vddproj project (Smart Device CAB Project). The INF file is as I guess generated by th e project and embedded into CAB file. How to set the InstallDir in VS project so that it gets correctly generated into CAB file? Thanks

Comment: Offhand I don't know how (or if) you can set it in a vddproj.  I never use that project type (which is telling since I wrote the how-to for the project for MSDN).  Studio creates the INF file for you from that project.  Personally I'd abandon the installer project and just use cabwiz directly from a batch file.  That's what we do here.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to continue using vddproj but only for generating INF file. Afterwards, I replace a target directory in INF file and use CabWiz to generate the CAB. Slightly problematic and I lost automation but it works.